# Knowing when user is using app in fullscreen mode? (iOS)

Tags: ios, css

I would like to know if it's possible to change html/css when user is using a webapp as a normal app on iOS.
Short: I would like to know when user are in standalone-mode (window.navigator.standalone?).
[Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.navigator.standalone){
   // Code here
}
```